# Internet Explorer 10, web fonts, and iframes

Tags: internet-explorer, font-awesome, webfonts

I have one page embedded in another via an iframe. The inner page contains the font awesome font on it. When I head to the URL of the inner page directly, the fonts load correctly. When the inner page is embedded in the other page, the fonts initially fail to load, on Internet Explorer only. If I reload the iframe only, then the fonts appear. If I reload the containing page, the fonts disappear again. If I visit the containing page in any other browser, the fonts work.

Things that are not causing this issue:

- IE is not in compatibility mode. It is explicitly set to IE=edge in both the containing page and the iframe.
- The fonts, iframe, and containing page are all being served from the same domain.
- Everything is being served over HTTPS. The page is not mixing HTTP and HTTPS content.
- The font-face declaration is set to format('embedded-opentype') rather than format('eot').
- Internet Explorer is downloading the EOT font successfully. This can be seen in the F12 developer toolbar.

Does anyone have any other ideas what could be causing this? If not, does anyone know of any workarounds?